# How to change default width of sidenav (drawer)

Tags: angular, angular-material-6, angular-material-5

How to customize default width of side-nav?
I have tried to change as in the documentation:

```
mat-drawer {
  width: 200px;
}
```

but it doesn't work. If I add !important then the expand functionality is not working
This is a code

```
<mat-drawer-container class="example-container" fullscreen autosize>
  <mat-drawer [@openClose]="menuState == 1 ? 'open':'close'" class="example-sidenav" mode="side" opened>
    <app-menu-top></app-menu-top>
    <app-side-menu-links></app-side-menu-links>
  </mat-drawer>

  <div class="example-sidenav-content">
    <app-header [configData]="configData" (onSearchButtonClick)="searchButtonClick($event)"></app-header>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Seems you missed `.` syntax of class in css, also try this class in your code -

```
.mat-sidenav {
  width: 200px;
}
```

PS:  It must be declared in the styles.css in your src folder (Global CSS file)

Comment: `mat-drawer` should work too, I think there is something else.

Comment: Due to the documentation it is mat-drawer, but .mat-drawer is not working as well. I can set width: 200px !important and it is ok but in that case the expanding is not working (menu state)

Comment: @TuviaKhusidDid you set it in your styles.css or on the css of the component? It must be in the styles.css in your src folder.

Comment: @Hypenate Yes exactly , forgot to add before, thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code in the css:

```
.mat-sidenav {
min-width: 200px }
```

Sometimes the component needs a minimun widthm when creating, and if it's expanding it auto-adapts to the width size.

Answer (score 0):

With Angular 13 I added the following style to the stylesheet of the component containing the drawer:

```
.mat-drawer.mat-drawer-side {
    width: 200px;
}
```